# Display text and Radio buttons in different lines

Tags: html, css

It may looks simple, but really tried lot before posting here.

We have **text & Radio buttons** as like below image in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81//yang-yin.html):

[image]

We need to display that in 2 different lines , in 1st line it should be text and in second lines it should show sizes [ L, M..etc ] as like [link2](http://stylebaby.com/maroon-solid-round-neck-t-shirt-conf.html)

[image]

**html**

```
<dt>
  <label class = required"
    <em>*<em>
    "Men T- shirt size : "
    :: after
  </label>
</dt>
<ul id ="options-456-list" class ="option-list">
  <li>L</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>XL</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>XXL</li>
```

**css**

```
.product-options ul.options-list label {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.product-options ul.options-list li {
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

I tried below code, but did't worked for me....

```
display: block; 

 li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

please help me solution with css

Comment: It can be done with JavaScript or JQuery, Is that OK for you?

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny  Thanks for suggestion, i got solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Clear:both` into ul list

```
.product-options ul.options-list {   
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i can accept answer in 7 minutes, thanks its working fine

Comment: You can also just remove float: left from the .required label

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<br>` in your HTML directly after the text? It's not pure CSS but it's pretty simple to add in.

```
<dt>
  <label class = required"
    <em>*<em>
    "Men T- shirt size : "
    :: after
  </label>
</dt><br>
```

[HTML br tag (w3schools.com)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i got solution..... i will use your idea in future for sure.....